# How to use the find funtion to search for the Value of a text box?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a userform that can bring up data using an ID number.

I am trying to reference a text box and select it, and then using it as a reference to fill out the Time and comments in the sheet. I think the is I cant put "txtID.Value" into the Find function.

Here is an example of my code:

```
Sheet1.Select
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="txtID.Value", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = txtTime2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = txtComment2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Find` function, it's recommended to use a `Range` object, and set it to the result. This method allows you to trap a possible scenario where `Find` failed to find a match in the searched range `Sheet1.Columns("A:A")`.

Also, try to avoid using `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveCell`, and use fully qualified `Range` objects (like in the code below).

**Code**

```
Dim FndRng As Range

Set FndRng = Sheet1.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=txtID.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then ' successful find
    FndRng.Offset(, 8).Value = txtTime2
    FndRng.Offset(, 9).Value = txtComment2
Else ' unable to fins the value in txtID
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & txtID.Value & " in Sheet1"
End If
```

**Note**: if you have this code outisde the `User_Form` module, then you need to add the `User_Form` reference when trying to get the `txtID.Value`.

For eaxmple, let's say the name of your form is `UserForm1`, then change this line to:

```
Set FndRng = Sheet1.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=UserForm1.txtID.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I put it in and it really worked well! I really appreciate your help! I will Let you know if it works through the whole workbook by tomorrow! thanks again!

Comment: @Mdaox seriously ? you prefer the other solution ? with using `Select` and `Selection` ?

Comment: His did work. However I did switch to your code to make it more reliable. Thank you for your help. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

To Make it work, you will have to put the code as below, which is quite self explainatory.

```
Selection.Find(What:=Userform1.textbox1.value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it really did help! I appreciate your help!